# Combine blender files

Tags: modeling

I have two different blender files on different devices I wanna combine with each other. Unfortunately I can‘t keep my material on the imported file and the animations don’t work anymore once I import them.
How do I solve this problem?
I tried to save the file I want to import as a fpx and export it and import it afterwards but some parts are missing the material I created in blender and the others are pink on the outsides (the objects I added material threw a picture). The animations don’t move and just stay the way they were when I exported them.

Comment: Use *File* -> *Append* and browse to the other blend file instead

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to append one file's content into another one.

To do that, head over to the *File → Append* menu. Navigate to the .blend you want to merge in, and open it.

From there, you can do things in several ways. If you want to just import all your 3D objects and their dependencies, go to the Objects folder, and select everything, then click *Append*.

However, you might be interested in keeping things somewhat separated, in which case you probably append the scene inside the *Scene* folder.